# Gridview checkbox losing information during sorting

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

So I have this checkbox inside a gridview, and it is working properly for the most part. However, I am trying to implement column-sorting to the grid, and it is causing an issue with the checkbox. When I do my initial fetch from the database, it populates the checkboxes properly, but when I click on a column to sort by it, all of my checkboxes get cleared out.

It seems that this is a problem with the Databind being done by the gridview, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My research into the issue makes me feel like I have it right, but I don't know for sure (legacy code: I hate it).

```
<asp:GridView ID="UserListGrid" runat="server"
    OnSorting="UserListGrid_Sort" AllowSorting = "True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="25" OnRowDataBound="UserListGrid_RowDataBound" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="UserListGrid_PageIndexChanging">
```

.
.
.

```
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="ActiveCheck" runat="server" SortExpression="ActiveCheck"/>                                                   
    </ItemTemplate>
```

.
.
.

```
protected void UserListGrid_Sort(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
        // ViewState["CurTab"] = 0;
        DataTable Data = myData.GetSessionRoster(TeamID);
        DataView UserListView = new DataView(Data);
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = myData.ConvertSortDirectionToSql(ViewState["SortDirection"] == null ? "" : ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString());
        UserListView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ViewState["SortDirection"];
        UserListGrid.DataSource = UserListView;
        UserListGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with my sorting? I can provide more code if needed.

As requested, here is UserListGrid_RowDataBound

```
protected void UserListGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        return;
    }
    // See which users are active
    CheckBox ActiveCheck = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("ActiveCheck");
    if (ActiveCheck != null)
    {
        ActiveCheck.Enabled = true;
        if (e.Row.Cells[11].Text.Equals("1") && !Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ActiveCheck.Checked = true;
            ActiveCheck.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also show what happens in UserListGrid_RowDataBound?

Comment: And this ending looks a bit strange: OnPageIndexChanging=">

Comment: Edited to add UserListGrid_RowDataBound and fix my asp that got cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're populating checkboxes not from the data base, but corresponding to the contents of your cell 11 (whatever it is). 
I appeal to this code line:

```
if (e.Row.Cells[11].Text.Equals("1") && !Page.IsPostBack)
```

While sorting you rebind your gridview, but you restrict populating and rebinding of your checkboxes on postback. This could be a reason for checkboxes loosing values.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for pointing this out. This bug has been bothering me all day, and all I had to do was take out the !Page.IsPostback. I think that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where you are saving data of your checkBoxes.  However, the good approach is to save all changes made by the end-user at every request to the server.  As far as I see, the data stored in the DataTable.  So, generally, you should browse through all grid rows, find CheckBoxes in them and save their values in this table.  This should be done in the Page_Load method.  This is necessary for the code in the UserListGrid_RowDataBound event handler to work properly.